# How Zope interface is implemented?

Tags: python, interface, zope

I tried to understand how Zope interface work. I know Interface is just an instance of InterfaceClass which is just an ordinary Class. But if Interface is just a class instance, why it can be used as a base class to be inherited from?

e.g. 
Class IFoo(Interface):
    pass

Could you give me some insights? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Python is inherently flexible, and *any* object can be a base class as long as it *looks* like a base class. As is always the case with Python, that means implementing some attributes that are expected to be found on a Python classes.

The Interface class (or it's bases Specification and Element) sets several. Look for any variables set starting with a double underscore (`__`) to gain an understanding:

- `__module__`: A string containing the python path module.
- `__name__`: The name under which the class was defined.
- `__bases__`: The base classes of this class.
- `__doc__`: (optional) The docstring of the class.

In addition, the InterfaceClass `__init__` method will be called when used as a base class; Python basically treats base classes as metaclasses, and a new instance of the base class's class (metaclass) will be created whenever we use it in a class definition. This means that the `__init__` method will be passed the new `__name__` and `__bases__` values, as well as all the new class attributes as keyword arguments (including `__module__` and an optional `__doc__`).

This is all documented in the [Standard type hierarchy section of the Python Data Model document](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) (look for the 'classes' paragraph on special attributes), and in [the same document, in the Customizing class creation section](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) (base classes with a `__class__` attribute are deemed a type).

So, *any* python instance that defines at least `__module__`, `__name__` and `__bases__` attributes, and a suitable `__init__` method will work as a base class for other classes. Python does the rest.

Comment: In Zope's interface implementation, there is such a line of code:

    Interface = InterfaceClass("Interface", __module__ = 'zope.interface')

Where InterfaceClass is an ordinary class.

Comment: @Zidadi You are quite correct, my answer is wrong, I'll see about getting you a correct answer.

Comment: @Zidadi Updated to explain how InterfaceClass is a metaclass.